# provider named pipes provider error 40 - could not open a connection to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-express

SQL Server Name : `ECARE432`
Instance Name : `SQLEXPRESS`

`app.config` contains:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="TimeTracker.Properties.Settings.myecareConnectionString"  
        connectionString="Data Source=ECARE432;Initial Catalog=myecare;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ecare123@" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have developed my first application in WPF (C#) with VS 2008 & SQL Server 2008. It works fine on my system. After deployment, it doesn't work on other systems.

It shows the following error message.

> provider named pipes provider error 40 - could not open a connection to sql server 2008

I have gone through Google and done the following steps but no use.

1. Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Native Client Configuration Aliases -> Alias Name -> ECARE432,1433, Port Number -> 1433, Protocol -> TCP/IP, Server Name -> ECARE432
2. TCP/IP is enabled. Protocols -> TCP/IP Properties -> IP1 -> Active - Yes Enabled - Yes, IP Address - My system IP address, TCP Dynamic Ports - Blank, TCP Port - 1433

   - IP2 -> Active - Yes, Enabled - Yes, IP Address - 127.0.0.1, TCP Dynamic Ports - Blank, TCP Port - 1433
   - IPALL -> TCP Dynamic Ports - Blank, TCP Port - 1433
3. SQL Server Browser is running.
4. Server Name is correct. No typo mismatch.
5. Client machine is able to ping my machine. (`PING ECARE432` is working)
6. TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 Exception added to Firewall. Also Turned off the Firewall in both my system and the client system.
7. `sqlbrowser.exe` is added to the Firewall Exception List.
8. Allow Remote Connections enabled under Connections in SQL Server Properties.
9. Visual Studio --> Tools --> Options --> Database Tools --> Data Connections --> Changed "SQL Server Instance Name" from `sqlexpress` to blank.

Please guide me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server Name: `ECARE432` and Instance Name : `SQLEXPRESS` - then you need to use `ECASE432\SQLEXPRESS` as the value for your `Data Source=` in your connection string:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="TimeTracker.Properties.Settings.myecareConnectionString"  
        connectionString="Data Source=ECARE432\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myecare;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ecare123@" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Along the same lines - if your instance really is called `SQLEXPRESS` - then why are you doing this??

> Visual Studio --> Tools --> Options --> Database Tools --> Data Connections --> Changed "SQL Server Instance Name" from sqlexpress to blank.

Makes no sense at all. If the instance **is** in fact `SQLEXPRESS` - let it be!

Comment: Yes. Instance is SQLEXPRESS, So I have changed the Visual Studio settings. But if I changed the Data Source as ECARE432\SQLEXPRESS then I m receiving the old following error - error: 26 - error locating server/instance specified. I m bit confused.

Comment: But with Management Studio, you **can** connect to `ECARE432\SQLEXRPESS` - right?? Is this a **remote** machine (e.g. some kind of a server) running SQL Server Express? The **Express** editions don't allow remote connections by default - have you explicitly enabled remote connections for your SQL Server Express instance?

Comment: See: [How to configure SQL Server 2005 Express to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277)

Comment: I have already enabled the remote connections for SQL Server Express instance. Now I have changed from ECARE432 to my system ip address in the connection string and the error fixed. But again I m receiving the another error like - system.indexoutofrangeexception: invalid index 2 for this sqlparametercollection with count = 2. Can you please help me out on this...

Comment: @user2230954: well, that latest error seems to be an application error - you'll need to ask a new question and provide the relevant code in your question in order for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, Marc. Its sqldbtype emuneration error and it was fixed. I have closed the question now.

Comment: If you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then you should [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.